# Tracking on google maps does not work on my android phone

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am new to Google map v2 development and am stuck at this point where in my phone (moto G android Version 4.4.2)the blue dot that tracks the user location does not move and even does not change to an arrow. I built the entire project based on Android V4.4.

I tested the same apk file on my friends phone (Note 2 Android Version 4.1.2) and it works.

MainActivity.java

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap)).getMap();
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but if you target your app minSDKversion to 19, it shouldn't work on a 4.1.2 which is API 16..

Comment: I tried to fix it by varying different versions between 2.2-4.4 but it still doesn't work. 
Any other solutions for this?